# Custom Button to open a Lightning Quick Action which launches a Flow

Tags: lightning-quickaction

Is there any way I can open a Lightning Quick Action which launches a Flow?
I have a Button in lightning component. On click of the button, I need to launch a quick action which opens a Flow. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible you cannot open a custom quick action from a lightning component (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CPOHQA4)

Comment: Oh is it? Thank you for replying.

Comment: If you are using Aura, why not just embed the flow in your component?  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm

Comment: Yes, i have implemented the same now, just embedded flow inside component.

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to one specific object, I believe it is possible.
Go to the Objects' setup page.

1. Go to "Buttons, Links, and Actions" and create a new action with Type=Flow
2. In the Page Layout, go to "Mobile and Lightning Actions", to add your action to the page.